# Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Text' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#

noob programmer here so sorry if I'm missing something really simple, here's my code:

```
namespace Programming_Assignment_2
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    string combination;
    const int MinLength = 6;

    bool CombinationCheck(string combination)
    {
        if (combination.Length > 5)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void btn_SetComb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        combination = My_Dialogs.InputBox("Please enter a password longer than 5 characters: ");
        if (combination.Length < MinLength)
            My_Dialogs.InputBox("Error! Please make sure password is longer than 5 characters: ");
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Thank you, password saved.");
        }
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void text_SafeStatus_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                    
      bool CombinationCheck;
      if (
        text_SafeStatus.Text("Combination Set"));
      else (
        text_SafeStatus.Text("Combination Not Set"));   
    }
  }
}
```

So the two .Text's at the bottom return the error in the Title plus I get a few more mini-errors here and there such as

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

at the bracket after the else..

Again sorry for what is probably a noob question but I can't seem to find answers that specifically help me

edit 1:

So the text error was fixed for me thanks but I have another problem which is trying to get the true/false value from a bool and using it to determine what the text box displays..

```
if bool CombinationCheck;
if CombinationCheck true;
text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination Set";
else
text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination Not Set";
```

that's what I currently have, I have no idea how to make this work.

Comment: if (combinationCheck) {text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination Set" } else {...}

Comment: @JeroenHeier How about `CombinationCheck? text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination Set" : text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination Not Set";`

Comment: @CameronFairbun, you should accept the answer solving your _original_ question and post a _new_ question for the _new_ issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `TextBox` text property, as there's no such method called `Text()`, so use assignment operator `=` to assign the value.

```
text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination Set";
```

And if you need to check the value of a `Textbox`, use `==` comparison operator, don't use single `=` for comparison, as per above example `=` is assignment operator and only used to assign a value.

```
if (text_SafeStatus.Text == "Combination Set")
    // do something //
```

**EDIT**

`CombinationCheck` returns true or false depending on the length of string you pass into the method.

Move this code snippet from `text_SafeStatus_TextChanged` to `btn_SetComb_Click` event. Paste it below the existing codes.

```
private void btn_SetComb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // .. existing codes .. //

    if (CombinationCheck(combination))
        text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination set";
    else
        text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination not set";
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply, that fixed that error. I have another problem which is how to use the value of a bool .. like this                      if bool CombinationCheck;
          if CombinationCheck true;
          text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination Set";
          else 
          text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination Not Set";

Comment: Also explain how to fix the `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement` error in line 48.

Comment: @Abdul I've used the updated code and it works but the problem I'm having now is the text box doesn't display combination not or combination set until i click on it and type.

Comment: @CameronFairburn it's because that code is inside text_SafeText_TextChanged event, how do you want this code to get executed?

Comment: I would like the text box to be defaulted as 'combination not set' and once the user inputs a string combination > 5 characters in length it should display combination set in the text box.

Comment: @CameronFairburn are these 2 different textboxes? user input 1 textbox and display "combination set/not set" on another textbox?

Comment: @Abdul They click a button which opens an inputbox which prompts them to enter a combination. Everything appears to be working besides the text box which won't display the values until I attempt to type in them.

Comment: @CameronFairburn Try the edited part.. remember to remove the codes inside TextChanged event, then just paste those 4 lines inside the button_click.

Comment: @Abdul Thanks, that worked for after the combination is set. I guess for before the combination is set I'll just make the default 'combination not set'